# how to define an object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to define an object with Key that's a MediaType value and with value that's an array of Person objects. How can I initialize that variable in my typescript class? Here's what I tried

```
elements: Record<MediaType, Person[]> = {};
```

Is that the right way to do so?

so elements would be like this

elements = {"application.color.test": [Person, Person, Person], "application.video.test": [Person, Person, Person]}

Where `application.color.test` is a MediaType.

Comment: What's `MediaType` and what's `Person`?  Presumably you want `Record<MediaType, Person[]>` (which is essentially just reading what you wrote, not sure why you'd put `Person` in there first... typo?) But right now this isn't a [mre] so it's impossible for us to tell. Please [edit] the code so that we can paste it into our IDEs to see what you're seeing. (Also, what happened when you tried it? It's not clear whether you ran into any sort of problem)

Comment: @jcalz I added more details. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah! As I understood correctly, that's the right way to do so.

Comment: Are you running into problems when following your own example with the Record type?

Comment:  I'm afraid I'm going to essentially repeat my first comment.  This isn't a [mre].  If you paste that code into a standalone TypeScript IDE, there are going to be errors where it says "What's `MediaType`? What's `Person`? `elements` isn't declared properly", etc.  Please fix those.   And again, what happened when you tried this? It's not clear whether you ran into any sort of problem. You said "I tried this" but not anything more. Did it fail in some way? Did it work but you're just... concerned that maybe it's wrong?