# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record

Tags: typescript

I have the following code

```
let elements : Record<MediaType, Person[]> = {};
```

I get the following error for the line above, where I initialize elements to an empty object.

```
 Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<ElementType, Person[]>': "application/vnd.element.animation+dcx", "application/vnd.element.audio+dcx", and 19 more.
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably should be using an [object type with an index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) here, rather than `Record`. `Record` enforces that all possible keys are set, if the list of possible keys is known at compile time.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your [other question today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78161953/2887218)? It looks quite similar; or do you want to close the other one as a duplicate of this?  And again, please define `MediaType` or `ElementType` and `Person` for us.  It would be appreciated if you'd respond to outstanding questions in comments on existing posts before opening new ones to be triaged.

Answer (score 1):

Type `Record` is defined as follows in [lib.es5.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1585C1-L1590C3):

```ts
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};
// keyof any = string | number | symbol
```

Thus type `RecordWithMediaTypeKey` defined as:

```ts
type MediaType = "CD" | "Stream"
type RecordWithMediaTypeKey = Record<MediaType, string>
```

is equivalent to:

```ts
type RecordWithMediaTypeKey = {CD: string, Stream: string}
```

Note that the keys are not optional, which explains your error.
If you want optional keys, you may use: `Partial<Record<MediaType, string>>`

I think the confusion comes from the fact that:

```
type RecordWithStringKey = Record<string, string>
```

is equivalent to:

```
type RecordWithStringKey = {
    [x: string]: string;
}
```

Note the usage of [Index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshAmBLAhgFXNAvFARAYQBEcoAfXAZWACcJkBbHAKFEigCUIBjAeyvgHVEwABZwkaDAGkIIKNg48%20AHjEp0kADRQAztUQA7AOYA%20RgHozUKwD0A-I2YZ2XXgKHDKVA4emz5L5V0vIy0g71MLKyg7IA)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `elements` to an empty object that is expecting an object with all of the keys defined in `MediaType`. Assuming you are not planning to define everything in the Record, you can try skirting around this by using the `Partial` utility type.

```
let elements : Partial<Record<MediaType, Person[]>> = {};
```

It is typically used here when not expected to define every Record Key in the object. If you plan on doing that, define the object while it is being created to avoid having to use the `Partial` type.